# Rails Can't Find NodeJS Even Though it is Installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, rvm

When I run "rake assets:clean" I get the error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system
```

There are several posts about this, but they all say "install nodejs"

I have installed nodejs though.

```
$ which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
$ nodejs -v
v0.10.25
```

And also nodejs legacy

```
$ which node
/usr/bin/node
$ node -v
v0.10.25
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.

```
$ rake about
...
Ruby version              1.9.3 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version          2.4.3
Rack version              1.4
Rails version             3.2.13
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
Active Record version     3.2.13
....
```

What is really killing me is that this was working fine until I tried to remove a binstubs warning by cleaning the bin directory.

I've tried to undo everything I did to fix the binstubs issue - going back to a clean version in git, reinstalling rvm, reinstalling ruby, reinstalling my gems. I'm out of ideas on how to fix this.

I wonder if it's something stupid like an issue with my PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/home/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/andy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/heroku/bin
```

Comment: Go to IRB and check what `File.executable?('/usr/bin/nodejs')` returns - this is more or less what happens inside ExecJS.

Comment: That for your response @katafrakt. It responds true - what does that mean?      1.9.3-p551 :001 > File.executable?('/usr/bin/nodejs')
 => true

Comment: It means that everything seems to be right and, frankly, I have no idea what the problem can be. I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks again @katafrakt. I just found the issue. It was, of course, a dumb one. At some point whilst trying to fix the binstubs warning I had added "PATH: './bin:$PATH'" to my local_env.yml file. Of course this file was excluded for version control as it contains some secure keys so when I rolled back my git version that line was still there. There goes some very wasted hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added "PATH: './bin:$PATH'" to my local_env.yml file. See comment above. Doh!